# Overstaying B1 Visa in Israel

Tags: visas, regulations, israel

A US citizen, arriving to Israel on a tourist visa, for 90 days. The visa will expire in a week, and the flight tickets are for two days later.

Going to the Ministry of Interior is out of the question for this short time.

"Hopping" to neighboring counties, is a huge hassle, since we are traveling with infants.

What are the consequences of flying out after the expiration date?
Any other option to consider?

Comment: Are you Jewish?

Comment: I'm not going to answer as this is all i've read online from people. But if its your first time, you're jewish and have family members who are citizens they usually just point out you've over stayed and nothing much happens especially playing ignorance and such a short overstay... really though you should have gone to the Ministry of Interior.

Comment: You usually can get fined per month you overstay and that is payable at the Ministry of Interior or some airports, a few days is usually not fine though. Compared to other countries Israel is fairy relaxed on overstays, specially if you're jewish

Comment: I figured as much. Long story, I prefer gambling with immigration, then paying for expensive flights